# Add a column in a dataset using numbers from a name vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a name vector called *Weight* which has for each name an associated number. For example:

```
Cat    5
Dog    1
Monkey 4
```

If a write *names(Weight)* the output is *"Cat" "Dog" "Monkey"*. but I can't select the number associated to Cat using *Weight$Cat*.

I have a dataset *df* with a column called animals.

```
 Animals

 Cat
 Cat
 Dog
 Monkey
 Cat
 Monkey
```

I need to create a new column named *weight* with the numbers associated to each animal. That is

```
Animals    weight
 Cat       5
 Cat       5
 Dog       1
 Monkey    4
 Cat       5
 Monkey    4
```

What I have is a loop (and it does not properly work) but I think that in R should be an easier way to do that.

Of course my dataset is much bigger than the write in the above example.

Comment: Maybe try to use `match`?

Comment: `stack` your vector and then `merge`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do `df$weight <- Weight[df$Animals]`.

Answer (score 1):

We can `match` `names` of `Weight` with `Animal` column and get corresponding `Weight`.

```
Weight <- c("Cat" = 5, "Dog" = 1, "Monkey" = 4)

df$Weight <- Weight[match(df$Animals, names(Weight))]

df
#  Animals Weight
#1     Cat      5
#2     Cat      5
#3     Dog      1
#4  Monkey      4
#5     Cat      5
#6  Monkey      4
```

---

As mentioned in comments by @markus we can also use `stack` and `merge`

```
merge(df, stack(Weight), all.x = TRUE, by.x = "Animals", by.y = "ind")
```

Comment: Why not simply `Weight[df$Animals]` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ahh..right, I missed that. That's much simpler and straightforward. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`(check note below, also change "Value" to "Weight"):

```
library(dplyr)
df_target %>% 
 left_join(df_cats,by="Animals")
```

Output::

```
  Animals Value
1     Cat     5
2     Cat     5
3     Dog     1
4  Monkey     4
5     Cat     5
6  Monkey     4
```

NOTE::

```
df_cats<-read.table(text="Cat    5
                      Dog    1
                    Monkey 4 ",header=F)
names(df_cats)<-c("Animals","Value")
df_target<-read.table(text="Animals

                      Cat
                      Cat
                      Dog
                      Monkey
                      Cat
                      Monkey",header=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert weight in a data frame and join into df

```
Weight <- as.data.frame(Weight, stringsAsFactors = F)
Weight$Animals <- row.names(Weight)

df %>%
  left_join(Weight, by = "Animals")
```